# Granular rendering control inside a knockout.js `foreach` control binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to knockout, and I can't seem to find this problem stated or documented elsewhere, though I suspect I might be missing something.

I have a `foreach` in my knockout template HTML as such:

```
...
<tbody data-bind="foreach: cfeeds">
<tr class="datarow" data-bind="css:{danger:discovered()==false}">
    <td><a title="View this feed" data-bind="text: name,attr: {href: view_url}"></a></td>
    <td data-bind="text: description, css:{'text-danger':discovered()==false}"></td>
    <td class="text-center" data-bind="text: sched_type"></td>
    <td class="text-center" data-bind="text: sched_data"></td>
    <td class="text-center" data-bind="text: moment(last_poll()).calendar()"></td>
    <td class="text-right">
        <div class="feedgraph">
          <!-- D3 chart container -->
        </div>    
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
...
```

In the last DIV with `class="feedgraph"`, I add (in this case) a D3 chart, which works fine when the DIV is outside the `foreach`. However, it appears that knockout will rerender the entire TR every time the JSON poll returns, whether the JSON contains a changed value or not, and my `.feedgraph` div gets emptied.

Relevant viewmodel blocks:

```
...
self.cfeeds = ko.observableArray([]);
...
    self.loadFeeds = function() {
        postJSON(ajax_uri+'get_site_feeds/',{'site_id':selected_site_id},function(d){
            self.cfeeds.removeAll();
            $.each(d['configured_feeds'],function(i,v) {
                self.cfeeds.push(new Feed(v));
            });
            setTimeout(vm.loadFeeds,5000);
        });        
    };
...
$(function(){
    vm.loadFeeds();
});
...
```

It seems to me that the knockout rendering should occur at the atomic TD level only when a bound value changes, rather than at the TR level as it appears to be doing.

Hence, my question is: Is there a way to keep knockout from rerendering the entire row in a `foreach`, and instead only rerender the TD cells that have a data-bind attribute and leave my D3 charts alone?

Comment: Knockout will only rebuild the objects that change in your observable array. You are probably making new objects every time you get your JSON. Just because the new object contains the same data as the old object doesn't make them the __same__ object.

Comment: Is it possible to update the properties of each object in `cfeeds` without actually replacing the object in the array?

Comment: Of course, you can set them like `obj.myObs(newValue)`. You could further optimize by adding `obj.myObs(data).extend({rateLimit: 1000})` (updates max. once every second).

Comment: @CrimsonChris: That sounds right, but you'll notice that the TD containing the DIV in question doesn't have a data-bind attribute at all. Are you saying that if the `cfeeds` observable is a different object, that the foreach will rerender the entire row anyway? I will look into that and update.

Comment: @grav3nimag3 yes. The children of your `foreach` binding are essentially a template that is rendered once for each entry of your `cfeeds` observable array. If your JSON update mechanism throws existing array entries away and replaces them with new ones, `foreach` will remove and re-add the template. Take a look at the [ko.mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html); it is able to update existing objects and might help you to make your update process less invasive.